# Problems with header in C

Tags: c, header-files, raspbian, time.h

I have this piece of c code that I am in charge of speeding up. The code is put onto a RasPi and compiled. Two years ago the code was put on and compiled and it works. Now when I try to compile the same file it says there's an undefined reference to 'clock_gettime'. I looked it up and that function is defined in time.h. I thought that maybe that header wasn't installed or called in the code. At the beginning of the code it does say #include  so that's not the problem. I checked if the time.h header was installed on the RasPi and it was there with the other headers. I opened it up with nano and the clock_gettime function was defined, so that's not the problem. What should I do? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you linked with `-lrt`?

Comment: "undefined reference" is a linker problem, not a compile problem. I think you need to link with `-lrt`

Comment: how do I do this?

Comment: @GordonJohnnyElder Time to learn how to link a library with your framework. Do you use a makefile ?

Comment: the cross compiler I use generated one but I don't know what it is or anything about it

Comment: _"how do I do this?"_  This depends on your build system. If you have something generating makefiles for you, there's probably a place to edit `LD_FLAGS` or something like that. You'll have to edit your question and provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

[clock_gettime(2):](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

> #include <time.h> 
>     ... 
>     Link with **-lrt** (only for glibc versions before 2.17).

Comment: Can you explain -lrt or link me to somewhere that explains it?

Comment: @GordonJohnnyElder `cc -o your_output_executable your_sources_or_object_files... -lrt` where `cc` is `gcc` or `clang` or a similar compiler.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying. What I think you are saying is if I am using gcc I should say in the command line " gcc filename.c -o outfile -lrt time.h" with filename being the file to compile and outfile being the compiled file. Is that correct?

Comment: @GordonJohnnyElder Just `gcc filename.c -o outfile -lrt `, assuming your whole program is in `filename.c`.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank You!